# Showing that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ from an $N(0,\theta)$ population

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to show that, for a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ drawn from an $N(0,\theta)$ population, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i^2$ is a sufficient statistic for theta.

I figured I would use the Factorization theorem so I looked at the joint pdf:
$$f(x_1,x_2...,x_n|\theta)=\left(\frac{1}{2\pi\theta}\right)^{n/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2\theta}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i^2}$$
The factorization theorem says a statistic $T(X)$ is sufficient if the joint pdf of the sample factors as
$$f(x|\theta)=g(T(x)|\theta)h(x) $$
I think, then, that I'm done because I can just let $h(x)=1$ or even $h(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^{n/2}$.

Is my use of the factorization theorem correct in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is perfect. Also, you can solve this problem simply saying that the *Exponential Family* includes the *Normal Distribution.* The proof is exactly what you did.